# Restrict use of program to certain devices

Tags: php

I have a timeclock program (written in PHP on the server) in use by my company.  We use it to collect time-in and out on a daily basis.  We currently allow anyone in our intranet to use it based on a flag in their employee record, meaning they have to be onsite to clock in at any device at our 9 different locations.  We also have a flag that says they can clock in from any device, anywhere.  This is for our traveling salesmen and management. Now they want 7 devices designated as "timeclocks" only and a flag assigning certain employees to only use those devices to clock in.  We are using iPads for those devices, mounted on the walls in various warehouses. They are in 5 different states, all on our intranet with various subnets (i.e. 192.168.xx.xxx).  Is there a way I can do this?  when I try to use any of the $_Server variables, the proxy server seems to be a problem.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but all of the client ip address's are being masked by the proxy server.

Comment: How are those 5 locations connect together? Set a proxy server at one of the location, and other four warehouse connect to the Proxy Server as a client?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer.  We have an intranet with internal ip's 192.168.1.xxx and 192.168.100.xxx, etc. One proxy Server at the corporate office.  I believe all external traffic goes thru it.

Comment: You can add other headers that you can use to identify devices. If they are filtered by the proxies, you could have a look at the headers you can get through, maybe you can append a device ID to one of them.